# Swift - Call subclass method on change in variable of super class

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have a superclass A and subclass B. Both are ViewControllers. The code is as follows :

```
class A {
    var a : Bool = false
}

class B : A {
    var b : Int = 10
    func changeB() {
        b = 20
    }
}
```

So, theres a variable a in class A. Whenever it changes, it should change the variable b of class B i.e. it should call a method changeB() which will update b.

One way to achieve this is use events to call the method **changeB()** which will update **b**.

Is there any other way to achieve the same thing?

This is just a template for others to understand. The actual problem is - Class A consist of map view and list view and it handles the switching between 2 views. Class B inherits A and has button on top of the view which should be shown only for list view and not for map view.

So, I want to change my **button.isVisible** property which is in **class B**, when the view switches between list view and map view which is handled in **class A**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `a` in your subclass so that you can call `changeB` from its setter.

```
class B : A {
    var b : Int = 10
    override var a: Bool {
        set {
            super.a = newValue
            self.changeB()
        }
        get {
            return super.a
        }
    }

    func changeB() {
        b = 20
    }
}
```